# Split record with large text column over multple records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table that stores textual reports; for a report it uses a column of type `image`, this column can store text with a maximum length of 32k. Now I need to read this table from an odbc link, it cannot read the field of image type.

I added extra columns:

```
alter table so1
add memotext varchar(max)
add memoseq int null
```

Now I can convert the text in the `image` column to the new column memotext:

```
update so1
set memotext = cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
where LEN( cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))) <= 7500
```

SQL Server limits this to around 8K in a record.

I would like to write a SQL Server 2008 procedure that splits the rest of the text to one or more extra records.

```
select 
    titre, memoseq, 
    len(cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))),
    left (cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)), 7500),
    substring (cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)), 7501, 7500)
from 
    so1
where 
    len(cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))) > 7500
order by 
    len(cast(cast(memo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))) desc
```

Table so1:

```
ColName   DataType  MaxLen  prec  scale  is_nullable  PrimKey
--------------------------------------------------------------
so0_nrid  decimal   9       15    0      1            0
memo      image     16      0     0      1            0
titre     varchar   30      0     0      1            0
rmod      varchar   32      0     0      0            0
nrid      decimal   9       15    0      0            1
```

Extra columns:

```
memotext  varchar   -1      0     0      1            0
memoseq   int       4       10    0      1            0
```

So if my source is:

```
so0_nrid   memo      titre   rmod       nrid      memotext  memoseq
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10000      text-10k  report  21aug2019  12345678  null      null
10001      text-20k  list    5jun2019   12345679  null      null
```

After inserting the extra records the result would be:

```
so0_nrid   memo      titre     rmod       nrid      memotext     memoseq
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10000      text-10k  report    21aug2019  12345678  1-7500       null
10000      null      report-2  21aug2019  new-rid   7501-10000   2
10001      text-20k  list      5jun2019   12345679  1-7500       null
10001      null      list-2    5jun2019   new-rid   7501-15000   2
10001      null      list-3    5jun2019   new-rid   15001-20000  3
```

`so0_nrid` is the foreign key to link the reports to the main table.

For the new records, new unique record ids need to be generated.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Also - `nvarchar(max)` should hold text up to **2 GB** in size - at 2 bytes per chararcter for Unicode, this translates to at least **1 billion** characters - not 7500 ....

Comment: "I have table that stores textual reports; for a report it uses a column of type image" The image data type has been deprecated since 2008 version, and also, it's a binary data type, not a textual data type.